# Real meaning of these linq querying styles

Tags: c#, linq

These linq queries can be written in both the ways. But choosing which way seems really to be confusing task. Please explain the difference in performance (if any) of these commands.

```
 from table1Details in objDataContext.Table1s where table1Details.SomeId == 15
                                           select new {....};

from table1Details in objDataContect.GetTable<Table1>() where table1Details.SomeId==15
                                     select new {...};
```

Comment: Well, the second one (as written) won't do anything.

Comment: There virtually is no difference. Look at the source code for the `Table1s` property, that should explain a lot.

Comment: You can use [Linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net/) to see what SQL is produced

Comment: @Nilesh He most definitely does not want, nor should add a call to .ToList().

Comment: WHY negative(----) :(

Comment: @RahulRanjan Most likely for lack of research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But choosing which way seems really to be confusing task.

Why? What is confusing about it? Don't both ways work? Did you read the [manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357220.aspx)?

> This method is the main entry point for querying. When a strongly typed DataContext is created, new generated properties encapsulate calls to this method. For example, a `Customers` property is generated that returns `GetTable<Customer>`.

`GetTable<T>()` just provides a generic way to access datasets, with runtime lookup (`GetTable<UnknownEntityType>()` will throw), as opposed to the generated, compile-time checked properties.

Comment: No, it does work both ways. But I just wanted to know if there was really any difference in terms of performance or any other..

Answer (score 3):

That's not a difference related to LINQ at all.  The data context is providing a property `Table1s`, which, internally, is just going to call `GetTable<Table1>()`.  It's a convenience method with virtually no performance cost and absolutely no functional difference.

Answer (score 1):

[DataContext.GetTable Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357220.aspx)

> This method is the main entry point for querying. When a strongly
>   typed DataContext is created, **new generated properties encapsulate
>   calls to this method**. For example, a `Customers` property is
>   generated that returns `GetTable<Customer>`.

So for your case, there is no difference. Your `DataContext` has a property `Table1`, when you directly access it using `objDataContext.Table1s` it calls `objDataContext.GetTable<Table1>()`